# Existence of a map $\phi:\mathbb{Z}_{N^2}^* \mapsto \mathbb{F} $

Tags: number-theory

Is there a map between the group of $\mathbb{Z}_{N^2}^*$ where $N$ is a composite number , a product of two equal size secure prime numbers $p$ and $q$ and a finite field $\mathbb{F}$, such that for all $x \in \mathbb{Z}_{N^2}^*$ there is a polynomial representation of $x \in \mathbb{F}$ ?

Comment: If we assume finite fields defined over congruent classes of prime numbers then $|\mathbb{Z}_F|=F-1$ The order of $\mathbb{Z}_{N^2}^*$ is $N\phi(N)$. Maybe there is sth with the crt and the isomorphism $\phi: \mathbb{Z}_{N^2}^* \mapsto \mathbb{Z}_{p^2}^* \times \mathbb{Z}_{q^2}^*$ but $\mathbb{Z}_{p^2}^*$ and $\mathbb{Z}_{q^2}^*$ are not defined modulo a prime

Comment: @fgrieu But from the isomorphism of the crt?

Comment: If you want to define a mapping between one set and the other, it's easy; you can define a mapping to $GF(2^{256})$ using SHA256.  However, presumably you also insist that the mapping also preserve the group operation; however any field has two operations defined on it; which field operation should the group operation be mapped to?  In other words, should $\phi(ab) = \phi(a)+\phi(b)$ or $\phi(ab) = \phi(a)\phi(b)$?

Comment: @poncho. the multiplicative one: $\phi(ab)=\phi (a)\phi (b)$

Comment: Sorry I thought a _map_ was bijective by definition (my math vocabulary in English is less than perfect). I stand corrected.

Comment: @tylo: actually, because he wants the multiplicative operation to be preserved, the appropriate order is $x^a-1$.  In any case, we can show that an injective map cannot exist; a surjective map (where surjective is defined to mean "we map to all elements of the field other than 0") does exist, however whether a nontrivial map exists in general is less clear.

Comment: **Every** function between finite subsets of $\mathbb R$ can be represented by a polynomial (just use the Lagrange interpolation polynomial). I would guess this transfers to maps from $\mathbb Z_{N^2}^*$ to $\mathbb F$, even though that polynomial might not be the simplest possible one.

Comment: @curious Please use the edit button to include your additional requirements into the question. (And it would also be useful adding some context how this relates to cryptography, for now this looks like generic math.)

Answer (score 1):

So if you want a homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}_{N^2}^*$ into the multiplicative group of a field, you have to adjust the number of elements in the field. With $p=2a+1$ and $q=2b+1$ (with $a,b$ prime), you have
$$|\mathbb{Z}_{N^2}^*| = 4pqab$$
The multiplicative subgroup of a field $F_{x^y}$ with prime $x$ and exponent $y$ has $x^y-1$ elements. At this point you could choose a specific $N$, that the according cardinalities match ($4abpq=x^y-1$), but if you have to apply this to arbitrary $N$, it won't work this way. Then all you can do is try to find $x^y$, s.t. $(x^y-1)$ is a factor of $4abpq$. If you use e.g. $\mathbb{F}_p^*$ or $\mathbb{F}_q^*$, this will work. But I can't think of any other fields which have this property from these given values.

As an example for an homomorphism you can use $f(x) = x^{pq(q-1)}$ to get a subgroup of order $p-1$, which you might be able to find an isomorphism into the multiplicative group of $\mathbb{F}_p$.

However, a bijective function (isomorphism) is quite unlikely to exist.

Comment: Actually, we know that a bijective function cannot exist (even if you omit the element 0 of the field).

Comment: Are you absolutely sure about that? Small number example: $p=3, q=5 \Rightarrow N^2=225, \phi(N^2)=120$. From the cardinality it would fit to the multiplicative group of $\mathbb{F}_{11^2}$, and both are cyclic groups wrt. their multiplication. And I think all finite cyclic groups are isomorphic to each other.

Comment: Actually, that's the problem: $\mathbb{Z}_{N^2}^*$ is not a cyclic group.